# Подключение консоли в программу.

Tags: c#, c++, консоль, linux

Приветствую Вас, гуру.

Есть вопросик, как можно прикрутить консоль linux (ну или ком строку win) в приложение, в виде окошка? Желательно на Шарпе или Плюс плюс. Сосно как тут:

[image]

заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программно запускаете нужную консольную утилиту и читаете её stdout и stderr, выводя полученное в окно своего приложения. Если ожидается обратная связь от пользователя - пишите ввод в stdin запущенной утилиты.

Comment: Нет никакого примера? Немного более полно усвоить как именно встраивать данную приблуду.

Comment: @falstaf, хотите сказать, что изображение  в вопросе это именно окошко приложения (может быть виджет тот же, что и у консоли) и оно само туда пишет текст, получаемый от запущенного им же инсталлятора, а вовсе не консоль, в шелл которой приложение подсовывает команды,  перехваченная у менеджера окон и вставленная в свое окно?

--

Очень может быть. Только это отрицательный ответ на вопрос ТС и много возни с рисованием в своем окошке.

--

@VaLenOK007, для реализации предложенного @falstaf метода (в \*nix) обратите внимание на *псевдотерминал* (**pty**), `select` и неблокируемый ввод-вывод.

Comment: Благодарствую, собственно это мне и нужно было. Всем спасибо